SwiftUI sheet doesn't see updated state value
Somehow, this sheet code doesn't see the updated value of my data state. The updated value can be seen inside the Button action, but not in the sheet. Why is that?
The output in my test is Button sees the new data and Sheet doesn't see the new data!
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: SomeDataClass? = nil
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button(action: {
                if let theData = self.data {
                    print("Button sees the new data")
                } else {
                    print("Button doesn't see the new data")
                }
                self.showSheet = true
            }) {
                Label("Tap me", systemImage: "folder.badge.plus")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAndWait {
                data = SomeDataClass()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            if let theData = self.data {
                Text("Sheet sees new data!")
            } else {
                Text("Sheet doesn't see the new data!")
            }

        })
    }
}

class SomeDataClass {
    
}


Use .sheet(item: ...) it is designed for this case, "Presents a sheet using the given item as a data source for the sheet’s content."   see also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)

It's a shame that the duplicate question link always refers to an old post with ad-hock workarounds
because .sheet(item: ...) was not available then.
Apple clearly mention to use .sheet(item: ...) in cases like this one.
